# Multiple sensors off one pin

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, vibration

I have multiple piezo sensors acting as vibration sensors. I am using a PIC microcontroller that only has 2 ADC. I want the circuit to function in such a way that if any of the sensors are hit and generate a response above a certain threshold then the PIC will flash a LED. I don't want to use a multiplexor for timing reasons and want to use just one ADC. Is there a component that will help me?

Comment: (Q1)  What's the duration of the peak?  (Q2) Do you need to know that the threshold have been exceed?  Or, do you also need to know the value of the peak?  (Q3) Do you need to know that threshold have been exceeded somewhere, and it doesn't matter on which sensor?  Or, do you need to know which specific piezo sensor had exceeded the threshold?

Comment: Q1 Peaks have short durations ~3ms and I am scanning several other digital sensors so need something that will be quick to scan through all the piezos. Q2 Just need to know the threshold has been exceeded. Q3 Ideally it would be nice to know which sensor exceeded the threshold but I can work with just knowing that a threshold was exceeded.

Answer (score 2):

Use an analogue mixer circuit based around an inverting op-amp configuration. The output from the op-amp will be the algebraic sum of all the sensors so if any generate a signal, this will be seen on the op-amp's output. Following the op-amp, a comparator can be used or just feed the input into one of the ADC inputs.

What you have to ask yourself is this: could two sensors receive an impulse in such a way that the combined output signal of both sensors is zero?

If this can happen then you should use a precision rectifier circuit (also based around an op-amp) on each sensor output - then sum them as above. This should mitigate against cancellations as only one half of the impulse-producing waveform will be amplified and no cancellations can occur.

Answer (score 1):

How about external ADCs connected to your micro by SPI? [MPC3008](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21295d.pdf) has 8 ADC inputs in a single chip.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest, but not the most accurate solution.
If the level of the signal is high enough, you can use a diode based circuit to find the highest level from all inputs and to transmit it to the ADC.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faCYFj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To keep the voltage drop low, you should use low power Schottky diodes.

In case of piezo sensors, which can generate relatively high voltages I'd also use the overvoltage protection.

By the way, does your PIC have an analog comparator, which can detect a voltage peak and generate interrupts? Otherwise you may overlook the voltage "spike"  generated your sensor, if the sampling frequency is too low.
In my circuit the C1 capacitor is used to extend the pulse, for more reliable 
sensing by ADC.

**Update**

If you want to connect the piezo sensor directly to the above circuit, you should ensure, that the charge does not accumulate (as diode lets the current flow only in one direction). For such a purpose I use circuit shown below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffJJtV.png)</sup>
Finally you can use a voltage follower to decrease the load of the sensor and to improve sensitivity to short pulses. The last version is the slightly modified circuit which I have used for the drum trigger.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fthHTF.png)</sup>

Diode D7 should be a low power Zener diode with Zener voltage near to the VCC. It limits the voltage (however you can omit it, and then the excessive voltage will be shunted to the VCC by the BC junction of Q1). The R5 ensures stability of the voltage follower.